# Blur Background when fragment Show and when API < 23?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is any way to blur background when fragment show?
every ways I was tried.
When I called `getForeground` in:

```
(container.getForeground().setAlpha(5))..
```

it is show to me ERROR under (`getForeground`)

> (Must API >=23)

and my application `minSdkVersion = 14`

Any way to implement method or class to blur background when sdk < 23 or when sdk = 14?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `getForeground()` method within FrameLayout:

```
container = (FrameLayout) findViewById( R.id.container);

container.getForeground().setAlpha(5); // 0 (opaque) -> 255 (invisible)
```

Or using [View.setAlpha(float)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)):

```
your_view_name.setAlpha(0.5); // 0 (transparent) -> 1 (opaque)
```